# How to find rows from one worksheet in a different worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I mainly want to locate where cells in workbook A are in workbook B. The cells of each worksheet in workbook B are red, so the located cells should become unfilled (as seen at the bottom of this code). The problem lies in my second for loop and I'm not quite sure how to search through workbook B using the copied cells from workbook A, or if there's a more efficient way to do this.

```
Sub Macro7()
Dim jcolumn As Range
wsht = InputBox("Enter Name of bucket: ")
Workbooks("A").Worksheets(wsht).Activate
    For Each cell In Columns("J:J")
        cell.Copy
        Workbooks("B").Worksheets(wsht).Activate
        Columns("J:J").Select
        For Each icell In Columns("J:J")
                jcolumn.Find(cell).Select
                With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this :

```
Sub YourRoutine()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim myFileName As String

myFileName = "C:\Users\Bernard\Desktop\test.xlsx" 'Put your full extension & filename here


Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(myFileName)
Set ws2 = wb2.ActiveSheet

'Set-up your parameters
yourCol1 = 1 'Change 1 to the column in which your data is located in "ws1"
yourCol2 = 1 'Change 1 to the column in which your data is located in "ws1"
firstWs1 = 1 'Change 1 to the row in which the first data is located in "ws1"
firstWs2 = 1 'Change 1 to the row in which the first data is located in "ws2"

'Locate last row of ws1
wb1.Activate
ws1.Activate
lastWs1 = Cells(Rows.Count, yourCol1).End(xlUp).Row

'Locate last row of ws2
wb2.Activate
ws2.Activate
lastWs2 = Cells(Rows.Count, yourCol2).End(xlUp).Row

'Loop through all the rows of ws1
For x = firstWs1 To lastWs1 
    wb1.Activate
    myData1 = Cells(x, yourCol1)

    'Loop through all the rows of ws2
    For y = firstWs2 To lastWs2
        wb2.Activate
        myData2 = Cells(y, yourCol2)

        If myData1 = myData2 Then

            Cells(y, yourCol2).Interior.Color = xlColorIndexNone

        End If

    Next y

Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**EDIT :** Edited my code a bit, as it was not tested, nor working. Now it is both tested and working.